# Is there a way to use Trello offline?

Tags: trello, offline

Sometimes I work on a bus or in places, where I can't use internet.

Is there a way to use Trello offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of January 27 2017, the Trello app for iOS and Android now works offline natively.

Different locales are seeing this roll out in a staggered manner but it should be available to you soon if it isn't already.

Comment: There's Focus|Project for Trello, a small app I'm developing that offers some read-only offline functionality now (2021 Q3) . Win 10+ and Linux are supported.

Please see https://f-p.app/snapshots.html or https://f-p.app/gallery.html.

(Sorry I can only comment at this point :) )

Answer (score 23):

There is currently no way to use Trello offline.

However, if you do go offline, Trello will inform you and will update your board when you're back online.

Comment: are there any plans to support this.  This is a big blocker.  Nothing worse than having a perfect list to only realize that you can't see it because internet connection is down

Comment: Leora, you can try the iPhone app, which stores your data offline. Adding offline support creates a lot of complexity (for both developers and users). User interfaces for merge conflicts are never simple. It's not out of the question, but it won't be coming in the near future.

Comment: i have the iphone app but i don't see any offline data. when i try to open when i am offline, the app is basically useless. do i have an old version possibly?

Comment: It should have the data from the last time you synced. However, it will only sync data from cards you have opened, not just cards you've seen in the list. For performance and bandwidth reasons, it doesn't load all the card data at once.

Comment: Bobby: referring to "it will only sync data from cards you have opened" – I can realize this becoming sluggish if carried out automatically, but would a full sync be considerable on an optional/manual premise? I.e. a sync-all button? (prompting user if there's more than `n` cards, that it might take some time, etc, etc. In my opinion, this might pose a workable compromise between having no pure offline mode and how it 'works' now.

Comment: is there a way to take a snapshot and/or download all the boards?

Comment: Is this correct as of 2013?

Comment: Nope. You can now export data for all boards. Menu > Share print and export > Export as JSON. Seems like the best solution for now.

Comment: Trello provides an API. It could be interesting to create an offline Trello project. https://trello.com/docs/

Comment: This feature is in Trello's Up Next list of Android app features: https://trello.com/c/ig5IZyJn/291-offline-support .

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2015, (question asked back in 2011) you still (!) can't do much offline beyond see lists of cards, but:

- The **Android** app now (since 27th May 2015) has "[Offline Support](https://trello.com/c/ig5IZyJn/291-offline-support)" in its "Working on" section (with a whopping 3122 votes - follow the link to vote and encourage them on). But don't get your hopes up, because here is what they say about it:

> Yes, we are working on this. We have a plan on what we need to do. It's a big project and it will be a long while before we have something to show you.

- For the **iOS** app, "[Edit while offline](https://trello.com/c/9PTAcL1Q/92-edit-while-offline)" has been in the "Todo" category since August 2013 (with an impressive 1543 votes - follow the link to vote and encourage them on). However, the following are apparently already  supported offline:

> You can currently:
>
> - create cards while offline
> - add comments while offline
> - upload attachments while offline
> - view cached boards while offline
>
> We are
>   working on expanding this. We have a plan on what we need to do. It's
>   a big project and it will be a long while before we have something to
>   show you.

- There's also a [**Windows 8 app**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/trello/9wzdncrfj2xk). However, I can't find an equivalent status board, and here's what one reviewer ("0035", 7/15/2015, can't link to review) says about using it offline:

> ...unfortunately, other than viewing my lists, I can't do anything [while offline]
>   without it falling apart.
>
> Any editing to my board (e.g. adding a
>   list, adding a card , editing card details) is usually not registered
>   and, in some cases, causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

**For the desktop users**: I am working on something that may help (Linux/Windows users for now)

It's called Focus|Project for Trello it's still in development (long story :) ) but I also am a user (on Ubuntu).

**See** https://f-p.app

It is **not meant to be a replacement for Trello** at all, but an addition: expect a "single card + list grid view" rather than a board or timeline.

**Do expect past board data + a growing offline mode, image editing, dark UI and a battery-friendly nature** rather than collaboration, chat, power-ups & animations.

[image: Entering Offline Mode in Focus|Project for Trello]

Feature-wise it might be more or less used **to bridge an hour or two of a journey or unexpected outage**, assuming the project planning part is mostly already done (eg. card members cannot be edited yet) and the app is in regular (not necessarily continuous) use - i.e. can update.

There are silly mistakes/bugs at this point, partly as I have been going for prototyping features for a while to see if things will work - I think it's soon ready to aim for a bit more seriousness again.

For now, I suppose it's better than nothing - do feel free to

1. **Try!** (of course)
2. Let me know your biggest pain point (only one please! I am snowed under ... I can't help spotting problems myself :) if there's visible interest - there's development I guess)
3. Show interest (but not be too hard - e.g. you may need to restart it after going back online to see the changes)
4. **Grab a license (on Win), whether free**, or even - somewhat speculatively - a pro and thereby support development