# Can I use Trello when I am offline?

Tags: trello, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to use Trello offline?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/is-there-a-way-to-use-trello-offline)

Since there is no "app" for macs, is it possible to use Trello when I am offline? Will it just sync when I get online? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/20242), Trello cannot be used offline. However, it will update your boards when you are back online.